# How to get photo description in python telegram bot api?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to get a photo description in telegram using python and Telegram bot api

> Function to get it:

```
from telebot import *
from config import bot
from tasks.sport import sport


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'text'])
def sport_photo(message):
    try:
        print(message.photo[0])
        if '#тренировка' in message.text or '#Тренировка' in message.text:
            sport(message)
    except TypeError:
        print(11111)
```

The bot receives a photo with a hashtag from the chat. If I try `message.text` I get TypeError. In message.photo only photo sizes like this: `[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000024036E03B80>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000024036E03AF0>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000024036E03940>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x0000024036E0F880>]`. In photo size this info `{'file_size': 1081, 'file_unique_id': 'AQADP7oxG0qkEEl4', 'height': 51, 'width': 90, 'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAICmGGhOnsbVNrGtpvmKuCHl6kEjgakAAI_ujEbSqQQSYIajNiAr9yaAQADAgADcwADIgQ'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when receiving photos (or other media). the description is found at `message.caption` instead of `message.text`

Try this:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'text'])
def sport_photo(message):
    try:
        print(message.photo[0])
        if '#тренировка' in message.caption or '#Тренировка' in message.text:
            sport(message)
    except TypeError:
        print(11111)
```